# How to accept the user response either as an int, or a char or a string. C#

Tags: c#

```
int number;

        do
        {
            DisplayMenu();
            number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //here need int, string, and char

            if (number < 0 || number > 6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occured!");
                break;
            }
        } while (number != 0);


        static void DisplayMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main Menu");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Calculate Sum ");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Calculate Average");
            Console.WriteLine("3) Display Numbers");
            Console.WriteLine("4) Display Poem");
            Console.WriteLine("5) Create Numbers Array");
            Console.WriteLine("0) To Exit");
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number that corresponds to your choice: ");
        }
```

I need to take the user input in integer, string, and character. Moreover, this code should then still work properly.

I was searching on other boards but there is no such thing I could find.

Comment: Your requirements are really unclear.  Maybe if you explained why you need to take the user input in three different ways.

Comment: How do you plan to differentiate between the number 5 and the character '5'? Otherwise take the input as a string. If `int.TryParse` succeeds it's an int, else if the length is 1 it's a character, else it's a string.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your code, it appears that you are asking the user to enter a single digit from 0-5 to select the next function. One straightforward way of doing this is to substitute the ReadKey() method and switch on the result. As a bonus, the menu will execute immediately without having to wait for the [Enter] key.

```
// Loop until a valid int is received.
bool exit = false;
while (!exit)
{
    DisplayMenu();
    switch (Console.ReadKey().Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.D0: exit = true; break;
        case ConsoleKey.D1: calculateSum(); break;
        case ConsoleKey.D2: calculateAverage(); break;
        case ConsoleKey.D3: displayNumbers(); break;
        case ConsoleKey.D4: displayPoem(); break;
        case ConsoleKey.D5: createNumbersArray(); break;
        default:
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number 0-5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            break;
    }
}
```